# the parameters in Admob.initAdmob when editing unity code

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob

I am currently editing my code as following:

```
Admob ad;
ad.initAdmob("admob banner id", "admob interstitial id");
```

My question is that I don't know the difference between admob banner id and admob interstitial id,(by the way, my English is not very good)

Comment: If I remember correctly, banner id is used for small banners that show at one corner of the screen. interstitial id is used when an ad displays in your entire view (and you have to click exit to close it).

Comment: thanks,it is my poor english that make me in trouble.

Answer (score 0):

When you click the create add section the first kind of add is banner and the second kind of add is interstellar.
[image: This is how banner look like]

[image: This is how interstital look like]

Well this is not English too but you can see the places from these images.
After you create your adds you can look their id from your created adds
[image: This is ids]

You can see add id from here, while you are creating your add give them a name inculude their type so you can find it later on here.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize Admob Unity Plugin

```
Admob.Instance().initAdmob("admob banner id", "admob interstitial id");
```

Admob id with format `ca-app-pub-279xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx`

Required two id one for [banner](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner) and another for [interstitial](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/interstitial) Ads.

Register your app in the AdMob UI and create your own ad unit IDs for banner and interstitial.

Comment: Thanks a lot,i konw the difference now!